# Is there a way to see what characters are in the types in ctype.h?

Tags: c, header-files

I am writing a C program that involves going through a .txt file and finding all the printable characters (or possibly graphical characters) that are **not** used in the file. I know that the header file ctype.h defines several character classes (e.g. digits, lowercase letters, uppercase letters, etc.) and provides functions to check whether or not a given character belongs to each of the classes, but I'm not sure whether it's possible to do the inverse (i.e. checking **all** the characters in a class for something). I need something that lists or defines all of the characters in each type, ideally an array or enumerated type.

Comment: Why don't you take a look at `ctype.h` yourself?

Comment: Are the names and descriptions of the macros not enough?

Comment: The number of characters available is limited, and depending on your encoding may be as low as 128. You can just call the `ctype`functions with each of them.

Comment: You looking for something [like this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Template:c/string/character_classes)?

Comment: @user3078414 -- if it were only that easy.... You can't. The best place to determine exactly what is included in each *character class* is the *man page*. An informational summary of what it included in each is [**ctype.h**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/ctype_h.htm) or [**isdigit(3)**](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit)

Comment: That's not possible, as you can manage different character sets with the same language (in this case C) Let's illustrate: if you use ASCII, the only chars allowed are from `NUL` to `DEL` (with codes ranging from `0..127`). If you use ISO-8859-1 you have codes ranging from `0` to `255`, and if you use Unicode, you have from `0` to `0x10FFFF` posible values.  So you must reconsider your question and think on a single encoding (or you will lead to print all the defined Unicode characters but the ones you use in your text file, case you are ambitious) and make your program useless.

Comment: @GusWiedey: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score?

Answer (score 4):

Dunno if this is helpful, but I wrote a program to classify characters based on those found in a given file.  It wouldn't be hard to fix it to go over the characters (bytes) in the range 0..255 unconditionally.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

static void classifier(FILE *fp, char *fn)
{
    int c;
    int map[UCHAR_MAX + 1];
    size_t i;

    printf("%s:\n", fn);
    for (i = 0; i < UCHAR_MAX + 1; i++)
        map[i] = 0;

    printf("Code Char Space Upper Lower Alpha AlNum Digit XDig  Graph Punct Print Cntrl\n");

    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        map[c] = 1;
    }

    for (c = 0; c < UCHAR_MAX + 1; c++)
    {
        if (map[c] == 1)
        {
            int sp = isspace(c)  ? 'X' : ' ';
            int up = isupper(c)  ? 'X' : ' ';
            int lo = islower(c)  ? 'X' : ' ';
            int al = isalpha(c)  ? 'X' : ' ';
            int an = isalnum(c)  ? 'X' : ' ';
            int dg = isdigit(c)  ? 'X' : ' ';
            int xd = isxdigit(c) ? 'X' : ' ';
            int gr = isgraph(c)  ? 'X' : ' ';
            int pu = ispunct(c)  ? 'X' : ' ';
            int pr = isprint(c)  ? 'X' : ' ';
            int ct = iscntrl(c)  ? 'X' : ' ';
            int ch = (pr == 'X') ?  c  : ' ';
            printf("0x%02X %-4c %-6c%-6c%-6c%-6c%-6c%-6c%-6c%-6c%-6c%-6c%-6c\n",
                    c, ch, sp, up, lo, al, an, dg, xd, gr, pu, pr, ct);
        }
    }
}
```

The extra trick that my code pulled was using `setlocale()` to work in the current locale rather than the C locale:

```
#include <locale.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    filter(argc, argv, 1, classifier);
    return(0);
}
```

The `filter()` function processes the arguments from `argv[1]` (usually `optind` is passed instead of `1`, but there is no conditional argument processing in this code) to `argv[argc-1]`, reading the files (or reading standard input if there are no named files).  It calls `classifier()` for each file it opens — and handles the opening, closing, etc.

Comment: Ok, that's pretty slick -- a nice tabular output of each *character class* applicable to each character in each file (or `stdin`).

Answer (score 2):

There is no fixed character list in `ctype.h` that could help you.  In fact `isprint()` depends on the locale.

Assuming that you're speaking of `char` and not wide chars, one way to solve your issue would be to initialize a table of 256 elements, each representing a char:

```
char mychars[256];  
memset(mychars, 0, 256);
```

then open your file and read all the chars, and flag those that are present:

```
...
int c; 
while ( (c=fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    mychars[c] |= 1;  
}
```

then later you can just iterate through the printable ones:

```
for (int i=0; i<256; i++) {
    if (isprint(i) && !mychars[i]) 
         printf ("%c not found\n", (char)i);
}
```

Comment: The `isprint()` (or `isgraph()` for that matter) seem to be the key to answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

1. Create an array of `unsigned long`s with 256 elements that can old the number of times a `char` occurs in the file.
2. Read the contents of the file character by character and update the data in the array.
3. After processing all the characters of the file, walk through the elements of the array and print the necessary information.

---

```
int main()
{
   unsigned long charOccurrences[256] = {0};

   // open the file.
   FILE* fin = fopen(....);

   int c;
   while ( (c = fgetc(fin)) != EOF )
   {
      // Increment the number of occurrences.
      charOccurrences[c]++;
   }

   // Process the data.
   for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i )
   {
      if ( isprint(i) && charOccurrences[i] == 0 )
      {
         printf("%c was not found in the file.\n", i);
      }
   }

   // Close the file
   fclose(fin);
}
```

Comment: I was typing a little bit slower than you ;-)   May I suggest to use an array of long instead of an array of int, in order to be consistent with the maximum number of chars that could be expected in a file (at least according to the return value of ftell()) ?

Comment: @Christophe, excellent suggestion. I changed it to `unsigned long`.

Comment: Missing argument in `printf("%s was not found in the file.\n");` and probably incorrect format anyway.

Comment: @chqrlie, thanks for pointing out the errors. I needed to use `%c` also.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all values of the `unsigned char` type, from `0` to `UCHAR_MAX` and check every function from `<ctype.h>` to determine what the classes are.

For example, you can list all digits with this:

```
printf("digits: ");
for (int c = 0; c <= UCHAR_MAX; c++) {
    if (isdigit(c))
        putchar(c);
}
printf("\n");
```